A Pretty Puzzling Problem Pertaining to Perplexing Poly-Chromatic Polyominoes
For this particular example we'll have 2 colors: red and blue. We'll also be using squares for this problem but you could have very similar problems using hexagons, triangles, or even pentagons and heptagons (if you use hyperbolic geometry).
Say you have x squares and these squares follow all of these requirements:

All the squares must exist in the same plane
From 1 square there is a path to another without needing to use a path that has some segment that is not on any squares.
If a pair of squares touches each other, the segment on which they touch each other must be exactly equal to the side length of that square.
All of the squares must be congruent.
One set of squares may not be connected to another set of squares purely through a diagonal.
No squares may exist on top of one another.

How many different combinations of squares are there given x squares and 2 colors (red and blue)? We consider 2 configurations of the squares to be the same if we can get one to look like the other using purely reflections and rotations.
I am well aware that the case where you use a single color is unsolved (as of December 26th, 2024). And if you use more than 1 color, it will probably be an even harder problem. However, I am still interested in hearing upper and lower bounds to the answer to this question.
Lets call the function that answers the single colored case P1(x) and the function that answers the 2-colored case P2(x). Here are the first few values to each of those functions*:

P1(1) = 1
P2(1) = 2
P1(2) = 1
P2(2) = 3
P1(3) = 2
P2(3) = 12
P1(4) = 5
P2(4) = 54
P1(5) = 12
P1(6) = 35
P1(7) = 108
P1(8) = 369
P1(9) = 1285
P1(10) = 4655

You may have noticed that I have stopped at P2(4). This is because it starts taking a while to find every possible combination and weed out the duplicates at P2(5). However, it is pretty straightforward.
*I didn't calculate the values for P1(x) myself; I got them from the OEIS sequence A000105.
